Windows Subsystem For Linux forgets everything
I am stuck on a Windows machine for work, but I work with Ruby on Rails, so everything I do has to be done through the Windows Subsystem for Linux. I did finally get it set up and working, but then I tried to get Elastic Beanstalk working. At some point in that process, something made my WSL wonky. Now, when I start it up, things look slightly different (the colors I set for the console aren't working; it's just all the default text color), and when I cd into my project directory and run rails c I get the following:
Command 'rails' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install ruby-railties

When I try to run bundle install, it gives me this error:
Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.5

When I test the plain ruby version with ruby -v it does indeed report
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

However, when I check it with rbenv versions, it only lists 3.0.5
  system
* 3.0.5 (set by /home/peterc/admin-tool/.ruby-version)

Ok, now for the really weird part: All works fine if I start it from something called "Tilix (Ubuntu)". The rails command works, the ruby version is correct, everything works. The trouble with that is that I can't change any of the settings in this Tilix thing. If I try to change the name of one of the profiles, it will show my new letter for the briefest instant, and then it just goes back to "Unnamed"
EDIT: I found one other person with this problem - https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/rqw0pf/changing_preferences_not_possible_in_tilix/ - but they did not get an answer. They indicated that if they "created a new user" it worked, but no idea how to do that with this application (can't find such an option in the gui).
Anyway, I can't help but think it has something to do with the Elastic Beanstalk (which is the way the team has been interfacing with AWS; maybe there's a better tool?), but I cannot for the life of me figure out what that might be, how to fix it, or even how to undo it.
I apologize for the lack of specific detail here, but I really hope someone else has had a similar situation and can guide me. I appreciate you all!

Similar issue I had with WSL, where commands were not found and failed. In the terminal, you get with default text color,it could be the default shell sh. Type bash then enter in that shell to see if will give you a bash profile which would have your user profile, and apt packages installed. Also try setting the ruby version globally in rbenv example rbenv global 3.0.5

It sounds like the core issue here is really that rbenv init is not being run when the shell is launched or you're launching into a different shell. I think you're having trouble finding a good answer as you're blaming WSL for something thats really the linux distro.

That was exactly it, @exception_thrown ! I don't know why it isn't starting up the correct shell when it did so not just a day ago, but triggering bash worked a treat! Rails is working again. Thank you so much for the very specific command to try. I appreciate you!

Thank you for your thoughts, @max ! I think you are correct in your general assessment, but without any specific suggestions or commands. I knew that rbenv and other things weren't being initiated, but had no idea why. I don't know what "launching into a different shell" meant until I followed the suggestions in the other comment. I figured it had something to do with WSL because that's what I used to launch the terminal in the first place. I appreciate you!
